# Slider extending beyond 100%

Tags: slider, powerapps

In my application I have used a slider with maximum value of 100.

When I made the application to fit in whole screen it is getting stretched and  slider is also getting stretched.

Slider image:

[image: Slider image]

How can I remove the extra line which is circled in the image.

Answer (score 0):

If your concern is about extra pixel after the slider circle, you should know its how should to be. Because, the little tail inform the user that its at max value.
So, if `Padding` and `Width` property doesn't solve the problem, try to used to it.

Comment: I haven't understood it. can you please explain it properly?

Answer (score 0):

Your label might say "100%" but your Handle is not at the Max of the slider Rail. You likely need to adjust the logic behind the "100%" label to include the max.

Comment: Handle is at the max of Slider Rail. It is showing correctly in normal screen i.e., preview mode but when i tried  to maximize the screen to fit the system screen size then it is getting stretched  and now it is as shown in that picture. when screen is stretched,  how can i make the handle at the end of the slider rail.